# Empty woocommerce cart when visiting page under specific parent page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I adjust this PHP code so that it empties the woocommerce cart when I visit a page under a specific parent page?

Example:

1. I visit [www.domain.com/anyparentpage/page](http://www.domain.com/anyparentpage/page)
2. nothing happens
3. I visit [www.domain.com/mtm-user/page](http://www.domain.com/mtm-user/page)
4. empties cart

`

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $post;
    $slug = $post->post_name;
    if($slug == 'mtm-user') {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

`

I tried adding $post->post_parent but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing slug with parent post id. here 31  is post parent id

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $post;
    $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
    if($parent_id == 31) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```